# The onbeforeunload event does not occur when the browser tab of appmaker web app closes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-app-maker

I intend to invoke the onbeforeunload event when the browser tab of appmaker app closes, for saving a manual-save mode datasouce's changes.

I write the code below in onAppStartScript.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  app.datasources.mydatasources.saveChanges();
}, false);
```

I preview my app in Chrome 69.0.3497.100 for PC, and make a change for mydatasources.
Then I close browser tab, but the change doesn't apply mydatasource.

When I keydown F5 in appmaker app, then beforeunload event is occured.

How can I save mydatasource changes, even if app-users close browser tab suddenly.

Comment: Are you planning to use this feature in Chrome only? IE and Edge doesn't support `beforeunload`

Comment: That is false, 'beforeunload' event does work in both IE and Edge, just limited.

Comment: @Observer I want to use this feature not only in chrome, but also in Chrome android and webview android, safari ios. according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload, it seems that I cannot use this feature in Safari iOS.

Comment: Did you think about "saving offline" feature? By that I meant, to save locally/cookie every step which you want to save to DataSource and clear it out if data successfully saved to DataSource. Every time when you load your website check if local storage/cookie has values then use them and save. It just a basic idea which requires a lot of implementation dependence on your application.

Comment: thanks for your reply, observer. I don’t think about offline saving feature. I just want to save to datasource when an user close browser tab of appmaker apps in manual save mode.